# javascript onsubmit and 2 functions error

Tags: javascript, function, validation, onsubmit

can someone please tell me what is going wrong?

I am trying to create a basic login page and that opens only when a correct password is written

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname2"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("password must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}

function isValid(myNorm){
var password = myNorm.value;
if (password == "hello_me")
{
return true;
}
else 
{alert('Wrong Password')
return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="helloworld.html" onsubmit="return !!(validateForm()& isValid())" method="post">
Login ID: <input type="text" name="fname"> <br />
<br>

Password: <input type="password" name="fname2" > <br />

<br />
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="Reset" value="clear">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one & missing. should be "return !!(validateForm()&& isValid())"

Comment: <form name="myForm" action="helloworld.html" onsubmit="return (validateForm()& isValid(fname2))" method="post"> use this

Comment: @Rizvi !!(true) == ture , this is not issue

Comment: @Aneesh, both functions are returning Boolean value.. so bitwise &  operator is also working same norms

Comment: tried all the comments, doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password value is `undefined` in 2nd function because you are not using any params when calling `isValid()` function

```
var password = myNorm.value; //`myNorm` is undefined
```

to

```
var password = document.forms["myForm"]["fname2"].value;
```

See below correct function

```
function isValid(myNorm){
 var password = document.forms["myForm"]["fname2"].value;
 if (password == "hello_me"){
   return true;
 } else {
   alert('Wrong Password')
   return false;
  }
}
```

**Updated Answer on comment**
if value is valid in function `validateForm()` then `return true`, see below

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname2"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("password must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

    return true; // return true when input value is value
}
```

[**<kbd>FIDDLE DEMO</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftwgX/2)

Comment: I did what you did here but the issue I am facing now is that the action is not working

Comment: @user2771301 , please see updated answer, `return true` in `validateForm()` when value is valid

Answer (score 0):

alert for wrong password in isvalid() needs a semicolon.
The And operator is && not & in the on submit call
I am just eye balling the code
What did you observe?
You cld use ie to debug using F12 key.. Or Firefox with the suitable plugin